# How to make floating label of the text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a box with a few sections of text. Each section will have a floating label on the left of it. However I have encountered a problem where the end of the text overflows onto the next section.
Is there a way to prevent this?

```css
.punktBox {
    width: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.punktSection, .punktSectionHalf {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    min-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.punktSecLabel {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="punktBox">
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Desc: </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris venenatis, felis id euismod lacinia, ligula sapien consequat augue, sed volutpat felis ipsum ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc porttitor nisl a suscipit suscipit.<i> (3 min lub mniej) </i>
  </div>
  <div class="punktSectionHalf">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Person: </div>John Doe
  </div>
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Lorem: </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add another wrapper? it yes it can be easy to achive with flexbox, CSS grid, table layout, etc

Comment: I can change the HTML structure however I want. Of course the less markup the better. I tried to wrap the text in `<span>`, but it didn't change the result.

Comment: add the span, and simply move `display:flex` from the container to `.punktSection, .punktSectionHalf` and remove float and your are done: https://jsfiddle.net/w5nyLqrh/1/

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif . This has solved my issue. What is the difference between `display:flex` and `display:inline-flex` here?

Comment: like the difference between block and inline-block .. basically inline-flex will fit the content while flex will always be 100% and take all the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest just use `inline-flex` and put your content inside a `<p>` or `<div>` element otherwise it will break.

```css
.punktBox {
    width: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.punktSection, .punktSectionHalf {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    min-height: 24px;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.punktSecLabel {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="punktBox">
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Desc: </div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris venenatis, felis id euismod lacinia, ligula sapien consequat augue, sed volutpat felis ipsum ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc porttitor nisl a suscipit suscipit.<i> (3 min lub mniej) </i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="punktSectionHalf">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Person: </div><div>John Doe</div>
  </div>
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Lorem: </div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and also remove float that become useless

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: inline-block` on your `.punktSection` and `.punktSectionHalf`, you're looking for `display: inline-flex`:

```css
.punktBox {
    width: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.punktSection, .punktSectionHalf {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    min-height: 24px;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.punktSecLabel {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="punktBox">
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Desc: </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris venenatis, felis id euismod lacinia, ligula sapien consequat augue, sed volutpat felis ipsum ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc porttitor nisl a suscipit suscipit.<i> (3 min lub mniej) </i>
  </div>
  <div class="punktSectionHalf">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Person: </div>John Doe
  </div>
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Lorem: </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pay attention to the `i` tag ... never make a text container a flexbox container

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you had a `float:left` on your punktSecLabel.
Just remote it, and add a `display:flex;` on your punktSection. Your content must also be wrapped in a bigger div.

Hope it helps !

```css
.punktBox {
    width: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.punktSection, .punktSectionHalf {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    min-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    display:flex;
}
.punktSecLabel {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="punktBox">
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Desc: </div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris venenatis, felis id euismod lacinia, ligula sapien consequat augue, sed volutpat felis ipsum ut ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc porttitor nisl a suscipit suscipit.<i> (3 min lub mniej) </i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="punktSectionHalf">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Person: </div>John Doe
  </div>
  <div class="punktSection">
    <div class="punktSecLabel">Lorem: </div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```